# window.print is not printing all the paginated data from table on IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, zk

Front end I'm using Javascript, HTML, CSS and backend Java technology.
IS it possible to print all of the records from the table if pagination do exists on press of print button which is using "window.print();"  ?  I'm Using Grid in zul page and setting data to grid by using Composer.

Comment: Is it a grid or listbox of zk?

Comment: @chillworld: Sorry for the late reply...it is grid

Answer (score 0):

`window.print();` will print only the contents on your current page. So if you have to use the `window.print()` you'll have to put all the data on the page you are about to print.